# Converting AS400 date to Oracle format

Tags: sql, oracle, ibm-midrange

I have a strange date format in AS400, that I need to convert to an Oracle date format (i.e dd-mm-yyyy).Below are dates which is stored in AS400.

```
101
820101
820101
820101
820101
820101
820101
820101
10728
820101
820101
820101
820101
```

Comment: Are you trying to do this in Oracle or in DB2?  What do the dates mean?  That is, please show the values that you want to produce for each date.

Comment: what are you using to preview the data? It looks like leading zeros are being dropped because it is numeric. The format is usually is yymmdd. As your system admin

Comment: Please edit the question and explain how these dates are to be interpreted. Thanks.

Comment: I am trying to migrate data from AS400 to Oracle using ODI. datatype in AS400 for this column is number.                        For Ex 01-Jan-2000 as 101(yymmdd) format 28-Jul-2001 as 010728.

Comment: I want date in dd-mm-yyyy format.

Comment: You should provide a sample for your date: I have `820101` and I want `01-01-1982`

Comment: I don't have ODI available, so don't know its capabilities. I'd expect it to be able to retrieve from a VIEW that presents the column as an actual DATE value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe your date are stored as some numeric data type? Simply left-pad your data with `0` before converting the corresponding string to date would solve your issue.

So if you need to convert your data to the `DATE` type, you will write:

```
CREATE TABLE T2 AS 
    SELECT TO_DATE(LPAD("AS_DATE", 6, '0'), 'RRMMDD') ORACLE_DATE FROM T;
--                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
--                    left pad missing '0'
--         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
--         convert to date with the correct format (I assume)
```

Please note the `RR` format that will take care to map the 2-digits years in the range 1950 to 2049

---

Even if I can't encourrage this, if for some reason you need to store your date as *strings* with the format `dd-mm-yyyy`, you will write something like that:

```
CREATE TABLE T3 AS
  SELECT TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(LPAD("AS_DATE", 6, '0'), 'RRMMDD'), 'DD-MM-YYYY') STRING_DATE FROM T;
```

See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/47e5e/1

Comment: Hi Sylvain i am getting error "ORA-01843: not a valid month
"

Comment: @raju Please provide a more significant data sample, as this works given your example.

Comment: The lead zero's aren't "missing", they can't be if the column is defined as numeric (zoned or packed decimal).  Most SQL interfaces suppress lead zeros in numeric fields when displaying a result set.

Comment: @Sylvain I took those datas from production datbase only.

Comment: @Charles Yes, you are right. I had hard time writing that in plain English. I rephrased the first few lines of my answer to something more correct, I hope. Feel free to edit/comment if this still need some work!

Comment: @Charles ? You need 6 characters for the date format I used. So, assuming the table column is numeric, without the left-pad Oracle will complain: `ORA-01840: input value not long enough for date format`.

Comment: @SylvainLeroux, LPAD by itself isn't going to be enough, as the column is numeric.  If Oracle had a DIGITS() function, that'd be perfect.  since it doesn't, you'd probably need `TO_DATE(LPAD(TO_CHAR(DATE400), 6, '0'), 'RRMMDD')`